# pandas window function first n instead of last n

Tags: python, pandas

From the pandas examples, we have rolling a rolling window that brings a window that starts from the top of the dataframe but aggregates to the last row within that window. I am trying to find an implementation that brings that same aggregation

An example of what I mean is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 1, 2, np.nan, 4]})
>>> df

         B
    0  0.0
    1  1.0
    2  2.0
    3  NaN
    4  4.0
```

Applying pandas rolling gets you this:

```
df.rolling(2).sum()
     B
0  NaN
1  1.0
2  3
3  Nan
4  4.0
```

What I'm looking for is something that aggregates at the first level:

```
df.rolling(2).sum()
     B
0  1.0
1  3
2  Nan
3  4.0
4  Nan
```

Are there any variations on the rolling that can do this? Note that I am using sum as an example, my true function is more complex but still intakes a rolling window.

Comment: df.rolling(2).sum().shift(-1) ?

Comment: df.rolling(2).sum().shift(-1)?